# HTML, CSS Inline Block Divs Jumping Out of Place

Tags: html, css

I've got a webpage with a parent div that has `text-align:center;` applied to it and multiple child divs with `display:inline-block;` but some of the thinner divs are jumping out of place on the page. You can see it [removed] where the last image on the page has jumped out of place and move up next to the image before it. The last single image on that page should be between the last two text blocks.

How can I stop the divs from jumping up out of place if their width is quite small?

If it's treating it as an `inline-block` element can I make the images start on a new line?

Code:

```
#article_container {
    width:749px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

.article_content_divs {
    width:720px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: It should be `text-align: center;`, not `centre`. You have to use the American English spelling.

Comment: It's the correct spelling in the source code, was just a slip of the keyboard on here :p

Comment: The image on the right should be under the box text box, not floating next to the two images (they are grouped with grey borders)

Comment: Nvm, just spotted a stray float attribute which seems to be causing the problems.

Comment: I just moved your fix to the answer you provided. Feel free to accept your own answer on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem was a float attribute, removing it has fixed it.

Instead of floating the child elements I've added a `clear:both;` to the elements and everything is aligning correctly.

Here is my updated code:

```
.article_content_divs {
    width:720px;
    // float:left; <--------- This was messing it up
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
   text-align:justify;
}
```